# Many to Many relation query with dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, join, where-clause

My tables are :

```
Table Emp:-
EmpId, EmpName

Table EmpDeptTrans:-
EmpDeptID, EmpID, DeptID

table Dept:-
DeptID, DeptName
```

Business logic is that one employee can work in multiple department and one department can have multiple employees, so basically its many to many relation.

i need help in forming the SQL query where i can put my conditions like:

`(dept='Engineering' and dept='Account' ) And (dept ='Library' or dept ='HR')`

my where condition is dynamic and can change based on requirement...

Comment: Sorry, but still can't get what you are asking. Can you please clarify your problem a little more ?

Comment: i wants to get list of all employees whose depart is based on condition written in above xml, as employee can belongs from multiple department, so i wants to findout those employee whose combination of deparment are based on rules (written in xml)... so basically i wants to write a sql query where i can put some condition for department and that can give me those employee who belongs from combination of those deparments

Comment: what is xml template in this case.

Answer (score 0):

as i can understand the question. is that you have written the condition in you xml data. where the expression could be something like

(dept='Engineering' and dept='Account' ) And (dept ='Library' or dept ='HR')

so what all you need to do is.

Create a plan query which show the all employee and department relation. 
now add your complex filter condition as you desire. like below

```
declare @complex nvarchar(1000);
set @complex = "(dept='Engineering' and dept='Account' ) And (dept ='Library' or dept
 ='HR')"

execsql query+' '+ @complex;
```

Comment: @J: i wanted help in forming query not the condtion.. :), though i have 4 different solution but still looking for best performing

Comment: So could you please share some of conditions more. then i think we can do it together.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, need more  input for best answer.

you can use IN for multiple department like..

select ....  where emptrans.deptid in('101','102')